# printing improper number of characters in a string

Tags: c, string

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
        char * name  = "bob";
        int x = sizeof(name);
        printf("%s is %d characters\n",name,x);
}
```

I have the above code.  I want to print the number of characters in this string.  It keeps printing `8` instead of `3`.  Why?

Comment: Have not used C in a while, but it seems that you are declaring a pointer (name) without initializing the memory. The pointer itself is just an address. There you need to use malloc (or whatever applies with your C compiler) to initialize that memory. Can you post more info on what compiler and options you are using and, if possible, tag it that way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`sizeof()` returns byte size.  Specifically, it gives the bytes required to store an object of the type of the operand.  In this case `sizeof()` is returning the byte size of a pointer to a string, which on your computer is 8 bytes, or, 64-bits.

`strlen()` is what you are looking for:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> // include string.h header to use strlen()

int main()
{
        char * name  = "bob";
        int x = strlen(name); // use strlen() here
        printf("%s is %d characters\n",name,x);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

use `strlen` for finding the length of a string.

Each character is atleast 1 byte wide. It prints `8` because `sizeof` gets a pointer to `bob` and, on your machine, a pointer is `8` bytes wide.

Answer (score 0):

`strlen` gives you the number of characters in a string.  `sizeof` gives you the size of the object in bytes.  On your system, an object of type `char *` is apparently 8 bytes wide.